# How to create a custom property for targeted audience within a sharepoint web part

Tags: web-part, properties

So I have an existing Sharepoint web part and I want to allow a button within that web part to hide or show depending on the users group, however I also want this to be configurable like the targeted audience property, unfortunately this affects the entire web part and not a single button within the web part. How do I achieve this ?